# Can IIS have https binding without certificate?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, lets-encrypt, kestrel-http-server

I tried to setup automatic Let's Encrypt certification for a domain using [this libray](https://github.com/ffMathy/FluffySpoon.AspNet.LetsEncrypt)
It is easy to setup and I hosted it in IIS.After some errors couldn't make it work.

Finally I tried running app with Kestrel as end server, without IIS and i automatically got certificate and everything worked fine.

But my requirement is IIS hosted application because I already have some applications hosted on IIS all of them behind port 80/applicationName/

First problem I came upon is and also my first question: **How can I even get to application using https(to auto get certificate) when I can't add IIS binding without certificate?**

I assumed I must UseHsts() and UseHttpsRedirection() so I added it to startup of my application.
After some time and few different combinations of settings I got it work partially.
My application got certificate from LetsEncrypt and reported no errors, but when I access it in browser on http I get redirect to https and nothing there.(Still no binding for https in IIS).

My second question would be: **How to properly configure https redirection from IIS to Kestrel in order to use my automatically acquired certificate?**

Answer (score 1):

create a dummy certificate in IIS, assign it to your site, save.

Go into IIS again and delete that certificate, if you check your bindings you'll find it as https, but certificate is empty.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty hard to relate this answer to the question.